# Migrating JEE @Produces to Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm migrating a JEE project into Spring Boot. I didn't find an equivalent for `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` as the JEE app uses it to inject configuration values that are written in the database:

In JEE we have a `Configurable` annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Configurable {

    String key() default "";

    String defaultValue() default "";

}
```

Plus an Stateless bean to produce the injected configuration. These function are the ones getting the configuration values from the database.

```
@Stateless
public class ConfigurationProducer {
    @Produces
    public String getString(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        String value = null;
        Annotated annotated = injectionPoint.getAnnotated();
        if (annotated.isAnnotationPresent(Configurable.class)) {
            Configurable configurable = annotated.getAnnotation(Configurable.class);
            String key = configurable.key();
            if ("".equals(key)) {
                key = injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName() + "."
                        + injectionPoint.getMember().getName();
            }
            value = getValue(key, configurable.defaultValue());
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Produces
    public Integer getInteger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        String value = getString(injectionPoint);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Produces
    public Boolean getBoolean(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        String value = getString(injectionPoint);
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(value)) {
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
        } else {
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }

    [...]

}
```

Then, each time we need a configuration value from the database, we inject it as follows:

```
@Inject
@Configurable(key = "active-configuration-key")
private Instance<Boolean> active;

@Inject
@Configurable(key = "url-configuration-key")
private Instance<String> url;

[...]

if (active.get()) {
    String target = url.get();
    ...
}
```

`@Instance` ensures we get the real DB value each time. This is very handy in the JEE application as we rely quite a lot on configuration that the user can update directly in the DB.

I didn't find out so far how to accomplish this on Spring. Worst case we can call a `ConfigurationService` each time we need a configuration key value, but before going in this direction I wanted to try to keep this Configuration Injection process. Any ideas?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `@Produces` allows you to create beans from any values, if so, you can use `@Autowired` to define any values to be used as beans in Spring

Comment: But what I didn't find with `@Autowired` is how to get information on the Injection Point. With `@Produces` I can get the name of the configuration key, go to the DB and retrieve its value that will be what is injected.

Comment: Having a generic dependency that changes based on the injection point seems like a bad design to me

Comment: It is similar to the @Value annotation in Spring, but instead of picking up the value from a properties file, it goes to the DB. The configuration key we are looking for is always the same it was at injection point, what could change is the value, that could have been updated in the DB. It would be as having a properties file that can be updated and persisted.